# remove duplicate script from github actions without using steps

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I have the following code:

```
###  CI WORKFLOWS
  matrix-ci:
    needs: [changes,git_diff]
    strategy:
          matrix: 
            include:
              - component: train-test-split
                component_dir: packages/train_test_split
                component_image: ${{needs.changes.outputs.train_test_split_image}}
                check_image_change: ${{needs.git_diff.outputs.train_test_split_image_name_change}}
                image_name: ${{ needs.git_diff.outputs.train_test_split_image_name }}

   
    secrets: inherit
    uses: ./.github/workflows/component_ci.yaml
    with:
      component_image: ${{matrix.component_image}} 
      directory: ${{ matrix.component_dir }}
      check_image_change: ${{ matrix.check_image_change }}

  matrix-cd:
    needs: [changes,git_diff]
    strategy:
          matrix: 
            include:
              - component: train-test-split
                component_dir: packages/train_test_split
                component_image: ${{needs.changes.outputs.train_test_split_image}}
                check_image_change: ${{needs.git_diff.outputs.train_test_split_image_name_change}}
                image_name: ${{ needs.git_diff.outputs.train_test_split_image_name }}

 
   
    uses: ./.github/workflows/component_cd.yaml
    with:
      directory: ${{ matrix.component_dir }}
      project_id: analytic-pocs-dev-c50df1
      package_path: ../../elrspModels
      artifact_registry_repository: ${{ needs.git_diff.outputs.artifact_registry_repository }}
```

I want to remove the duplicate code,and the solutions which have been mentioned require 'steps' which i am not using in my jobs. How can this be accomplished.

Thank you